# How to preserve backslashes in MySQL Queries?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database and a value in a column of a table is a string that is something like "{1,1,{1\,1\,1\,}}". When I use a select query it returns "{1,1,{1,1,1,}}", is there anyway to preserve the slashes so, if I were to echo the result, I would get "{1,1,{1\,1\,1\,}}" Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the whole query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this statement in your session :

```
 SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';
```